# System of linear and quadratic congruences

Tags: congruences

Solve the system:

$x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod {7}$

$2x-4\equiv 0\pmod {6}$

Completing the square for first equation gives:

$$(2x+1)^2\equiv 4\pmod {7}$$
$$y^2\equiv 4\pmod{7}\Rightarrow y_1=2,y_2=5$$
$$2x+1\equiv 2\pmod{7}\Rightarrow (2,7)=1|7\Rightarrow x=4$$
$$2x+1\equiv 5\pmod{7}\Rightarrow (2,7)=1|4\Rightarrow x=2$$

Second equation:

$$2x-4\equiv 0\pmod{6}\Rightarrow (2,6)=2|4\Rightarrow x=2,x=1$$

One particular solution of the system is $x=2$.

How to find general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved the quadratic congruence correctly, but the solutions of $2x-4\equiv 0\pmod{6}$ are $x\equiv \{2,5\}\pmod{6}$.

Divide everything by $\gcd(2,4,6)=2$: $$\iff x-2\equiv 0\pmod{3}\iff x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$

$$\iff x\equiv \{2,5\}\pmod{6}$$

The solutions of $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ are $x\equiv \{2,4\}\pmod{7}$ (as you've found).

There are $4$ solutions of the whole system: $\begin{cases}x\equiv 2\pmod{7}\\x\equiv 2\pmod{6}\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}x\equiv 4\pmod{7}\\x\equiv 2\pmod{6}\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}x\equiv 2\pmod{7}\\x\equiv 5\pmod{6}\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}x\equiv 4\pmod{7}\\x\equiv 5\pmod{6}\end{cases}$. Use Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the $4$ solutions of your system.

Comment: Solutions will be mod 42.

Comment: That's right.${}$

Comment: Remark useful for beginners: the linear equation modulo 6 has 2 (>1) roots (2 and 5) because $\mathbb Z_6$ is not a field; the quadratic equation modulo 7 must have just 2 (=the degree 2 of the equation) roots (2 and 4) because $\mathbb F_7$ is a field

Comment: @Ataulfo The quadratic equation mod $7$ can also have $0$ solutions.